# Make first item (or padding) of SingleChildScrollView not scrollable and delegate the touch events

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a `Stack` with two `Column`s.

First column contains contains only one child *(1)* with `InteractiveViewer` which has defined height (for example 250). It changes its content's zoom and translation based on scroll offset of `SingleChildScrollView` from second column. It shouldn't be pushed out of the screen while scrolling, so it's under the scroll view in a stack.

The second column have `SingleChildScrollView` with top padding *(2)* **OR** first view *(3)* that matches the *(1)* height.

Now I'd like to make the **top padding (2)** **or** **view (3)** not scroll the `SingleChildScrollView` but pass those touch events to `InteractiveViewer`. Doesn't matter whether the solution use padding or empty view, I just wanted to note here than what I want can be achieved with padding or view. I tried both but failed.

I tried the `GestureDetector`, `IgnorePointer` and `AbsorbPointer`, but seems like the `SingleChildScrollView` always get the touch events. I haven't found a way to make the top padding not scrollable too.

Basically I'd like to achieve something similar to the attached gif, except that I don't need the *"Collapsing Header"* text animation and app bar. Just pay attention to the mountains that hide below the scroll view. The scroll view should take entire screen once the scroll offset is equal padding/view height (250 in this example).

Is that possible somehow? My logic behind `InteractiveViewer` is way more complicated than the example provided below, I just simplified it to make the question easier to understand.

```
 Stack(children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Container( // (1) Widget that should get the touch events
                height: 250,
                child: InteractiveViewer(...)
              ),  
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250), // (2) Either not scrollable padding
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(height: 250), // (3) or not scrollable first item
                      Container(...)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]);
```

[image]

Comment: You can add a padding widget at first column

Comment: @jitsm555 yes, but that won't let the SingleChildScrollView cover the InteractiveViewer once it's scrolled top

Comment: I need to try at my end with InteractiveViewer

Comment: this is what `CustomScrollView` is for - just with two `slivers`: `SliverPersistentHeader` and `SliverList`, no need for any other things

Comment: @pskink yes, that's would solve the problem, but `SliverPersistentHeader` is resized when you scroll. My `InteractiveViewer` can't be resized as it contains multiple widgets. For example one of the widgets is google map, which doesn't really support smooth resizing. This solution is not acceptable for me. Is it possible to have the same behavior without resizing the `SliverPersistentHeader`?

Comment: what is wrong with resizing `SliverPersistentHeader`? it does not mean that its child widget will resize too

Comment: I tested the solution again and it seems that the child is resized. So how can I keep the child height const during scroll?

Comment: `OverflowBox` class, the docs say: *"A widget that imposes different constraints on its child than it gets from its parent, possibly allowing the child to overflow the parent."*

Comment: Ok I'll try to use `OverflowBox` and confirm if it works for me. Unfortunately the solution doesn't allow me to interact with the map inside a `SliverPersistentHeader`. `CustomScrollView` gets the touch events instead of the map, so instead of scrolling map vertically the `CustomScrollView` is scrolled and header collapsed. How can I dispatch the touch events in `SliverPersistentHeader` child only?

Comment: @pskink OverflowBox doesn't really work here. The first item is rendered a top of other items, so it looks like `SliverPersistentHeader` doesn't collapse. I have not found a way to change the widget order.

Comment: so clip the child: `ClipRect` / `ClipRRect` / `ClipOval` / `ClipPath`

Comment: @pskink what about the touch events? How to handle touch events only inside `SliverPersistentHeader` child and not in `CustomScrollView`? That's a blocker here, this is basic problem mentioned in my question that I couldn't find a workaround for.

Comment: i added `ListVide.builder` inside `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` (both vertical and horizontal) and it works just fine: scrolls only `ListView` - not parent `CustomScrollView`

Comment: @pskink could you post the code as an aswer? I can't get it to work as expected, I think I may miss something or I got wrong order of widgets. Would be great to see your solution!

Comment: i already deleted that code: it was simply `ListView.builder` returned by `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate.build` method, nothing fancy

Comment: Ok, but my nested child isn't `ListView`. It's `InteractiveViewer` which has it's own gestures and it seems like `CustomScrollView` wins to handle the touch events before `InteractiveViewer` can do this. Maybe nested `ListView` works fine, but not nested `Widgets` that also handle touch events in their own way. Any ideas what should be changed in `InteractiveViewer` to make it handle the touch events?